# is it possible to create a webscraping application that uploads the newest 'content' from a website onto my own website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, web-scraping

I am looking to build an application that displays 3 different website's newest content/update/changes onto my own website/application, this can be done through a link to the new content but a visual image is what I'm looking for that the link can be attached to. I'm new to programming and am just seeing if this is a viable project to work towards. Cheers for any help :)

Comment: You might be able to use an iframe. You could also have a server update an image that your web app uses as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible**

You can make an Api with python and In python you can scrape data with [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and requests packages and just call the Api from your javascript and update it in html when you get new data

*Hope It Helps*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).